# vba how to check a double column combo for a value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a double column combo and I use the value in column(1) as my answer but when I want to check if that combo has a value using this code it does not execute so when I try to retrieve the value from a combo I get run time error 381.
here is my code

```
 If Trim(CmBCodes.Value) = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please fill in the journey Code"
    CmBCodes.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
    End If
```

and changed that to this

```
   If Trim(CmBCodes.Value) = Null And Len(CmBCodes.Value)) = Null Then
    MsgBox "Please fill in the journey Code"
    CmBCodes.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
    End If
```

and still this code does not execute even if the combo has no value selected so it goes all the way to the piece of code where I try to retrieve the value and throws an error 381 here

```
  ws.Cells(iRow, 2).Value = UCase(CmBCodes.Column(1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If no selection has been made then combo and list boxes have a listindex of -1

```
If CmBCodes.ListIndex = -1  Then
    MsgBox "Please fill in the journey Code"
    CmBCodes.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If
```